# [Flutter]The numbers in the list are of unequal width, which looks ugly

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
ListView.builder(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Icon(
              Icons.info,
              color: randomColor,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              '$index$index$index$index$index$index$index',
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
  itemCount: 10,
)
```

[image]

The length of the number is equal, but the width of `1` is smaller than `8`. This is not beautiful. How to deal with it?
I tried to change it to a typeface of equal width,I wonder if there is any easier way?

Answer (score 9):

I think of a monospace font when i read your question.

I also found an article, where there seems to be a solution that is worth trying:

```
style: TextStyle(
    fontFeatures: [
      FontFeature.tabularFigures(),
    ]
  ),
```

Reference: https://medium.com/flutter-community/font-features-in-flutter-320222fc171d

Could you give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

I think jaop's answer is correct.

Nice monospaced fonts available here: https://fonts.google.com/?category=Monospace&preview.text=1234&preview.text_type=custom

In pubspec.yaml:

```
flutter:
  fonts:
   - family: RobotoMono
     fonts:
      - asset: fonts/RobotoMono-Regular.ttf
```

In widget:

```
 child: Text(
      '12345',
      style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'RobotoMono'),
    ),
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying to find the same width without changing the font.